# jQuery Responsive Mobile Menu

Tags: jquery, hover, toggle, transition, fade

The following functions work, but it doesn't look clean and there is probably a better way to achieve what I've done. Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. If the viewport is resized, even by 1px, the styles for the mobile button are removed. Also, the class 'active' is removed.
2. On click the 'mobile-nav' element is displayed and slides down and 'active' class is added.
3. I try not to rely on CSS3, I'm trying to get a a :hover transition working. So when I hover over the `.menu-button` it smoothly transitions to the `.menu-button:hover` styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sm5zy/11/

```
// Mobile Menu Button
$(window).resize(function () {
    $(".menu-button").removeClass("active");
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    $(".mobile-nav").removeAttr("style");
});

$(".menu-button").click(function () {
    $(".menu-button").toggleClass("active");
});

$(".menu-button").click(function () {
    $(".mobile-nav").slideToggle(250);
});
```

Comment: You are attaching to functions at the same event, I think this can be better http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Sm5zy/12/

Comment: That's exactly the clean up I was looking for :) Thanks!

Comment: Good! If the answer if what you looking for consider to accept it: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching to functions at the same events (window resize and menu-button click), is better to call the two functions in the same event handler like:

```
// Mobile Menu Button
$(window).resize(function () {
    $(".menu-button").removeClass("active");
    $(".mobile-nav").removeAttr("style");
});
$(".menu-button").click(function () {
    $(".menu-button").toggleClass("active");
    $(".mobile-nav").slideToggle(250);
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Sm5zy/12/